# CSS OnHover text, image should be displayed

Tags: css, image

i want to have a word like "here" and when I hover over it, above the word, there should be displayed an image.
I found a lot of code how to replace an image on hover or do something else but I want it like that: Above the text, and the style in the background should not be disturbed.

Comment: Some examples of what you've already tried would be great!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="comment">Here
<img class="image" src="https://g.twimg.com/business/page/image/11TwitterForSmallBusiness-300_1.png">
</div>
.comment .image {
   display: none;   
}  

.comment:hover .image {
   display: block;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mWk8x/)

Comment: Very nice, thanks. Can you add code that the Text before and after will not changed in design through the image? at the moment the image will be displayed and the text after the image will be not be able to see any more.

Comment: @Kovu sorry i am not able to get you properly, can you please clarify or even better edit and re post fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample for that,

```
<div class="here">Here</div>
<img src="link/to/file.png" class="image" alt="photo" style="display: none;" />
```

jQuery code is required for this, you cannot do that using CSS.

```
$('.here').hover(function () { // on hover
   $('.image').show(); // show the image..
}
```

The remaining will be applied using CSS, such as

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
```

And all other CSS properties can be applied to the image directly, but show that image using `.show()` from jQuery, you can't do that in CSS.

Comment: OP has not tagged this ques with jquery